# Is it possible for Windows explorer to notify my application when the path in the address bar has changed?

Tags: c++, winapi, explorer

I have Win32 c++ application which handles files and folders. I would like to be notified whenever the location in the address bar changes (i.e. the user enters/exists a folder).

Does explorer provide an event system for notifying applications of such events? If not can this be achieved in any other way?

Comment: In what way does your application "handle" files and folders? What technologies and API functions are you using? Did you read the documentation for other functions in the same category?

Comment: It's a sync application. I use Win32 API. Why is this relevant?

Comment: First of all, the Win32 API is _huge_. You need to be much more specific if you want us to be able to tell you how to modify your application to perform this task. It's only relevant as long as you actually want an answer.

Comment: Which address bar? There can be many.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't even know if [huge](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff818516.aspx) is a big enough word to describe it. :) connectionist- What are you trying to accomplish? See also [What is the XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan this one: http://screencast.com/t/oIzofXHeb

Comment: Not an answer, because I think you are asking for Y instead of X and I don't have the time to dig up the details, but look at the [IShellWindows interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc836570). It lets you enumerate "Shell Windows", which is Explorer, IE and possibly others, gives you an IUnknown to it and lets you register a handler to listen for new windows. From that IUnknown you have to find your way to the address bar.

Comment: @theB My application has something called "special folders". They're ordinary folders but they have special meaning to users. I want to sent a notification to the user (via a simple dialog) whenever s/he is browsing a "special folder". This is what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Then you might want to write a [Shell Namespace Extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144095).

Comment: It looks like this is what I'm looking for: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc836574 But is this only possible via a Shell Extension?

Comment: I use the following UI solution in my project: http://i.stack.imgur.com/y1QCX.jpg At the bottom of the Explorer window you can see the message of my program. It appears only when user enter my "special folder". It can be created with BHO + DockingWindow.

Comment: I don't understand. I want to be notified when the location in the address bar has changed.

Comment: The screen shot you provided does not match your question. You wanted to be notified when the user views the folder, which suggests that you want the notification to be displayed by your program. But in the screen shot, the notification is being displayed *by Explorer*. For that, you need a shell namespace extension with a custom view. And it won't work if the user sees the folder contents by other means (e.g. in search results, or if they right-click the folder and select Properties).

Comment: Ok. Can you please confirm that in my shell extension I would have to implement IShellWindows::OnNavigate ?

Comment: Imho, NSE is overhead.